# representing a character at various array in an html table w/JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've run into some issue graphically representing some of my data via J Query in my Hangman game- right now I'm working on the last part of my play(space) function to take into account if there is more than one correctly guessed letter in a word & to display all instances of that letter- I've made a function to loop through the array created out of the split word, I'm getting the correct indexes of those letters, I'm just kind of stuck as to how to display these letters at these indexes in my table via J Query correctly & I'm kind of stuck... I've been console.log - ing my data & I'm getting the correct data (the letter and the indexes of that letter in my array), I now just need to figure out how to display these letters in my html table at their correct indexes corresponding to the table (I'm feeling kind of stuck & wondering if this is possible to salvage- I'm sure there must be a way to do it, I just haven't figured it out- I'm not sure if I should be creating a dictionary object to pair the correct letter w/it's indexes in the array to use .each() to loop through to graphically represent in my table or if there's a way to graphically represent it w/the data as is). I'd really appreciate any help.

Here's my code:
JS/JQuery:

```
var wordBank = ["modernism", "situationalist", "sartre", "camus", "hegel", "lacan", "barthes", "baudrillard", "foucault", "debord", "baudrillard"];
var word = [];
var wrongGuesses = [];
var rightGuesses = [];
var images = [gallows, head, body, armL, handL, armR, handR, legL, footL, legR, footR];
var y = 0;
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  function randomWord() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordBank.length);
    var toString = wordBank[random];
    console.log(toString);
    word = toString.split("");
    console.log(word);
  }
  randomWord();

  function wordSpaces() {
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      $(".word-spaces > tbody > tr").append('<td data-idx=i>' + word[i] + '</td>')
    }
  }
  wordSpaces();

  function play(space) {
    //indexOf()==inArray() 
    var lIndex = jQuery.inArray(space, word);
    console.log(lIndex);
    if (lIndex == -1) {
      wrongGuesses.push(space);
      var wrong = wrongGuesses.length;
      console.log('wrong ' + wrong);
      $('.wrongLetters tbody tr td:nth-of-type(' + wrong + ')').text(space);

//      $(this).css("background-color", "#ff4500").fadeIn(300).delay(800).fadeOut(300);
      $(images[i - 1]).hide();
      $(images[i]).show();
      i++;
      $("html").css("background-color", "#ff4500").fadeIn(300).delay(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(100);
      console.log(word);
    } else { 
      console.log(word + "word"); 
      console.log(space + "space");
        function getInstances(word,space) {
          var indexes = [], w;
          for(w=0; w<word.length;w++ )
          if (word[w] === space)
          indexes.push(w);
          return indexes;
        }
      console.log(word + "word"); 
      console.log(space + "space");
      var indexes = getInstances(word, space);
      console.log(indexes);
      rightGuesses.push(space);
      console.log(rightGuesses); 
      $(".word-spaces tbody tr td:nth-of-type(" + indexes + ")").css('color', 'black');
  //    rightGuesses.push(space);

    }
  }

  $(".form-control").keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == 13) {
      var space = $(this).val();
      play(space);
      $(this).val('');
      endGame();
      return false;
    }
  });


  function endGame() {
    if (wrongGuesses.length >= 10 || rightGuesses.length == word.length) {
      $("body").css("background-color", "#ff4500");
      $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
    }

  }

});
html:
<header>
  <h2 style="font-family:paganini;">
    Hangman
    </h2>
</header>
<main style="font-family:paganini;">
  <figure class="hangman">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gSxmkUf.gif" id="gallows" align="middle top">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Mb4owx9.gif" id="head" align="middle top" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xkXISte.gif" id="body" align="middle top" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/U44ReUi.gif" id="armL" align="middle top" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/49kkaQF.gif" id="handL" align="middle top" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tqtNazW.gif" id="armR" align="middle top" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ydnz7eX.gif" id="handR" align="middle top" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dlL7Kek.gif" id="legL" align="middle top" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3AQYFV9.gif" id="footL" align="middle top" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/j9noEN7.gif" id="legR" align="middle top" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kJofX7M.gif" id="footR" align="middle top" style="display:none;">
  </figure>

  <table class="word-spaces">
    <caption>Your Word is: </caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <fieldset class="guessIn">
    <legend>
      Guess a Letter
    </legend>
    <label for="form">Type a Letter then Click <b>Enter</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="form" class="form-control" placeholder="guess">

  </fieldset>

  <table class="wrongLetters">
    <caption>Letters Guessed Wrong:</caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, next time, if you make a jsFiddle showing the error, your question will likely get more attention ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you make a selection you get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-of-type

That's because of this line:

```
$(".word-spaces tbody tr td:nth-of-type(" + indexes + ")").css('color', 'black');
```

Since a correct guess can set multiple indexes, you'll need to use a loop for the correct guesses like this:

```
$.each(indexes,function(e,i){
    $(".word-spaces tbody tr td:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").css('color', 'black');
})
```

---

Additionally, I think this line is wrong:

```
 $(".word-spaces > tbody > tr").append('<td data-idx=i>' + word[i] + '</td>')
```

You probably meant to use the value of i like this:

```
$(".word-spaces > tbody > tr").append('<td data-idx='+i+'>' + word[i] + '</td>')
```

(though you dont really need the data-idx attribute at all since it will always be the same as the child index within the tr tag and you're using that to get the cells anyway)

#### [Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/unzjakt0/23/)

Comment: I actually just fixed it like this:

Comment: sorry, I actually just fixed it like this: indexes.forEach(function (index){
      $(".word-spaces tbody tr td:nth-of-type(" + (index + 1) + ")").css('color', 'black');
      });   @DelightedD0D I'm not sure if this also works

Comment: oh, wow, I didn't know about the :eq() selector- maybe I should change the earlier one as well to include this? Thanks 4 your help! @DelightedD0D

Comment: @H.Hirschfeld Honestly, I didnt think `:nth-of-type` was a jQuery selector, but it appears it is, I have always used `:eq()` which can also be used like `$(".word-spaces  td").eq(0)`. If nothing else, its shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my own (I sort of panicked) like this: first I created a .forEach loop to loop through the word, then the issue was the difference btwn array concatenation in JS & html/css... I creates the index variable, and added one & also an additional plus sign outside of the parenthesis... So, this solves the problem:

indexes.forEach(function(index) {
        $(".word-spaces tbody tr td:nth-of-type(" + (index + 1) + ")").css('color', 'black');
      });

Comment: Good for you that's funny that we finished at the same time.

Comment: :-) I'm almost done w/the entire game @zer00ne but I'm so stuck on this last little part- I got everything done & working, everything functioning but then I had 2 make the form only take input of Single letters (no #'s, no spaces, etc. just a-z) & I've been working on it now for 24hrs+ (I have 2 take a quick break & take 2 midterms now) & Still can't get this simple restriction 2 work w/o totally messing up my display &/or game function (representing right guesses as wrong, etc.)- I feel like there's a simple solution I'm not seeing or maybe my syntax is wrong? I'll post a link

Comment: here's a link if u have any time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470222/restricting-keyboard-input-with-keypress-jquery @zer00ne - I feel like u understand the flow of my  game better than anyone (I tried conditional statements at all diff places in this function & 2 no avail)- maybe I'm just not Seeing what I'm doing wrong? Anyways, sorry 2 bother u, if u have a spare moment, maybe u cld take a look- I'm kind of freaking out ;-) ... Hope u r having a great day & thank u 4 all of your help- I learned Alot doing this...

Comment: Did you take a look at [**version 2**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35428672/2813224)? It accepts only a single character, along with some other important features. So you need a character filter? I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it does everything now. In addition to the [first version's features](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/0fa56t3s/), version 2 has the following:

- If a letter is guessed wrong more than once, an alert will inform the player of doing so and ignore it.
- If a correct guess has more than one letter, all letters will be exposed.
- Improved `endGame()` function with a message, but it needs one more fix, I'll leave that one to you ;-)

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1fEeBYNnElgJ55RcxNiA?p=preview)

```html
<!doctype>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>35387864</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        html {
            font: 400 16px/1.428 'Verdana';
        }
        
        main {
            padding: 20px;
        }
        
        footer,
        header {
            padding: 5px 20px;
        }
        
        footer {
            border-top: 2px ridge #666;
        }
        
        header {
            border-bottom: 2px ridge #666;
        }
        
        .wordSpaces,
        .wrongLetters {
            border: 1px ridge grey;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
        
        .wordSpaces td,
        .wrongLetters td {
            border: 2px inset #BBB;
            width: 3ch;
            height: 1.5rem;
            padding: 1px;
            text-align: center;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .wrongLetters td {
            color: red;
        }
        
        .form-control {
            width: 10ch;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        ul {
            font-size: 1rem;
            list-style: none;
            padding-left: 0;
        }
        
        .msg {
            font-size: 0;
            color: #000;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h2> Hangman </h2>
    </header>
    <main>
        <figure class="hangman"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gSxmkUf.gif" id="gallows" align="middle top"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Mb4owx9.gif" id="head" align="middle top" style="display:none;"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xkXISte.gif" id="body" align="middle top" style="display:none;"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/U44ReUi.gif" id="armL" align="middle top" style="display:none;"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/49kkaQF.gif" id="handL" align="middle top" style="display:none;"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tqtNazW.gif" id="armR" align="middle top" style="display:none;"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ydnz7eX.gif" id="handR" align="middle top" style="display:none;"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dlL7Kek.gif" id="legL" align="middle top" style="display:none;"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3AQYFV9.gif" id="footL" align="middle top" style="display:none;"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/j9noEN7.gif" id="legR" align="middle top" style="display:none;"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kJofX7M.gif" id="footR" align="middle top" style="display:none;"> </figure>
        <table class="wordSpaces">
            <caption>
                Your Word is:
            </caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <h1 class="msg">
</h1>
        <fieldset class="guessIn">
            <legend> Guess a Letter </legend>
            <label for="form">Type a Letter then Click <kbd>Enter</kbd></label>
            <input type="text" id="form" class="form-control" placeholder="guess" maxlength="1" required/>
        </fieldset>
        <table class="wrongLetters">
            <caption>
                Letters Guessed Wrong:
            </caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387864/hangman-gameplay-in-javascript">Hangman Gameplay in JavaScript</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/0fa56t3s/">jsFiddle</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var wordBank = ["modernism", "situationalist", "sartre", "camus", "hegel", "lacan", "barthes", "baudrillard", "foucault", "debord", "baudrillard"];
        /*var wordBank = ["xxxbnvkllyyybns"];*/
        var word = [];
        var wrongGuesses = [];
        var rightGuesses = [];
        var images = [gallows, head, body, armL, handL, armR, handR, legL, footL, legR, footR];
        var img = 1;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            function randomWord() {
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordBank.length);
                var toString = wordBank[random];
                console.log(toString);
                word = toString.split("");
                console.log(word);
            }
            randomWord();

            function wordSpaces() {
                for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
                    $(".wordSpaces > tbody > tr").append('<td data-idx=i>' + word[i] + '</td>')
                }
            }
            wordSpaces();

            function play(letter) {
                var wIdx = jQuery.inArray(letter, word);
                var wrong = wrongGuesses.length;
                if (wIdx === -1) {
                    if (wrong === 0) {
                        wrongGuesses.push(letter);
                        $('.wrongLetters tbody tr td:first-of-type').text(letter);
                        hangman();
                    } else {

                        for (var j = 0; j < wrong; j++) {
                            if (wrongGuesses[j] === letter) {
                                alert('The "' + letter + '" has already beem played.\nPlease try again.');
                                return true;
                            }
                            console.log('wrong' + wrong);
                        }
                        wrongGuesses.push(letter);
                        $('.wrongLetters tbody tr td:nth-of-type(' + (wrong + 1) + ')').text(letter);
                        hangman();
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var w = 0; w < word.length; w++) {
                        if (word[w] === letter) {
                            W = w + 1;
                            $(".wordSpaces tbody tr td:nth-of-type(" + W + ")").css("color", "black");
                            rightGuesses.push(letter);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $(".form-control").keypress(function(event) {
                var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                if (keycode == 13) {
                    var letter = $(this).val();
                    play(letter);
                    $(this).val('');
                    endGame();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            function hangman() {
                $(images[img - 1]).hide();
                $(images[img]).show();
                img++;
                $("html").css("background-color", "#ff4500").fadeIn(300).delay(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(100);
            }

            function endGame() {
                if (rightGuesses.length == word.length) {
                    $("body").css("background-color", "rgba(0, 185, 41, .3)");
                    $(".msg").text(word + " is correct!\nYou win!").css("font-size", "24px");
                    $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
                } else if (wrongGuesses.length === 10) {
                    $("body").css("background-color", "rgba(227, 0, 0, .3)");
                    $(".msg").text(word + " was the answer.\nYou lose.").css("font-size", "24px");
                    $(".form-control").prop('disabled', true);
                } else return false;
            }

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```